# Finitely generated $R$-module has a free resolution of length at most $1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, free-modules

If $R$ is a PID and $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module,

**How do I show that M has a free resolution of length at most $1$?**

So I have to show that M has a free resolution

$....\to F_2 \to F_1 \to F_0 \to 0$ with $F_i = 0$ for all $i > 1$

I know that every $R$-module $M$ admits a free resolution

$....\to F_2 \to F_1 \to F_0 \to 0$

But I don't know how to proceed from here

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain

Comment: @morrowmh I read that  this theorem could be used, however I don't know how, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Note what it implies about submodules of finitely generated free modules in this context.

Comment: use the structure theorem and ask yourself, what is a length 1 free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for any positive $n$ and a length 1 free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$? Put those resolutions together.